# How to use fortran90 subroutines in python with Cython and iso_c_bindings

Tags: python-2.7, fortran90, f2py

Up until recently I've been using IDL for the majority of my computational problems.  One of my most frequently used routines is a bit of fortran90 code, wrapped in C and called from IDL using the CALL_EXTERNAL function (none of this written by me).  For various reasons I'm moving the majority of computations to Python, but I haven't worked out a good way to incorporate the fortran code.  It seems that F2PY is the most obvious way to, however in practice the resulting module seems to be quite unstable.

Basically I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach the issue.  It seems that it should be relatively straightforward to rework the existing C wrapper and Cython to use the code from Python, though I have to confess I'm completely ignorant of C/Cython and quite new to python, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference I'm including the existing C wrapper below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bvls(int argc, void *argv[]) {

extern void bvls_(); 
int *n, *m, *nsetp, *index, *ierr;     
double **a, **b, **bnd, **w, **x;   
double *rnorm;

a =     (double **) argv[0];
m =     (int *)     argv[1];
n =     (int *)     argv[2];
b =     (double **) argv[3];
bnd =   (double **) argv[4];
x =     (double **) argv[5];
rnorm = (double *)  argv[6];
nsetp = (int *)     argv[7];
w =     (double **) argv[8];
index = (int *)     argv[9];
ierr =  (int *)     argv[10];

bvls_(a,m,n,b,bnd,x,rnorm,nsetp,w,index,ierr); 

}
```

**EDIT:**  After mentioning this to someone else they suggested that it should also be possible to use the fortran ISO_C_BINDINGS module to interface with Cython directly, bypassing the need for the intermediate C wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean by the `f2py` created module being "unstable"?

Answer (score 0):

The C wrapper you are currently using doesn't lend itself very well to be exposed to Python. You probably want a function signature in Python mirroring the Fortran signature and not the awkward signature of the existing C wrapper.

Whether you keep a C wrapper or make the Fortran function C interoperable with ISO_C_BINDINGS ultimately doesn't matter for interfacing with Cython. You only need to know the signatures of the C functions in your library you want to expose.

Either way, it's a simple case of following the Cython tutorial for [Interfacing with External C Code](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) and let Cython know the signature of the function you are want to expose. Assuming you want to mirror the Fortran signature, it would look like this:

```
cdef extern from "bvls.h":
    void bvls(double* a, int m, int n, double* b, double* bnd, double* x,
              double rnorm, int nsetp, double* w, int index, int ierr)
```

Then it's straightforward to create a function that's idiomatic to call from Python. You probably want to allow the caller to pass in a NumPy arrays for all the `double*` arguments:

```
cimport numpy as np

def pybvls(a, int m, int n, b, bnd, x, double rnorm,
           int nsetp, w, int index, int ierr):
    cdef double *a_, *b_, *bnd_, *x_, *w_
    # Get the raw data pointers from NumPy arrays
    a_ = <double *>np.PyArray_DATA(a)
    b_ = <double *>np.PyArray_DATA(b)
    bnd_ = <double *>np.PyArray_DATA(bnd)
    x_ = <double *>np.PyArray_DATA(x)
    w_ = <double *>np.PyArray_DATA(w)
    bvls(a_, m, n, b_, bnd_, x_, rnorm, nsetp, w_, index, ierr)
```

Finally you'll probably want to write as `setup.py` file to use distutils to build an extension module for you as described in [the Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html).